# Why doesn't the procedure return the data ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have been working on this query which should return data that falls between specified daterange but it doesn't. It returns the data that whether falls or not between range.

@DateTo
@DateFrom are of DateTime type;

```
If(@fk_UserRoles_WebUsers_RoleID = 1) BEGIN
SELECT Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID,
       Cases.CaseTitle,
       Cases.CasePetitioner,
       Cases.CaseNo,
       Cases.CaseLetterBy,
       Cases.CaseEntryDateTime,
       CaseHearings.pk_CaseHearings_ID,
       CaseHearings.Responder,
       CaseHearings.Supervisor,
       CaseHearings.Judge,
       CaseHearings.IsOpeningDate,
       CaseHearings.IsOpeningClosingDate,
       Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.ClosingDate, 106) AS ClosingDate,
       Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.ReOpeningDate, 106) AS ReOpeningDate,
       Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.OpeningDate, 106) AS OpeningDate,
       CaseHearings.IsConveyed,
       CaseHearings.IsClosingDate,
       Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.HearingDate, 106) AS HearingDate,
       Cases.fk_ConcernedOffices_Cases_ConcernedOfficeID,
       CaseHearings.CourtOrder,
       CaseHearings.CaseRemarks,
       ConcernedOffices.ConcernedOfficeName,
       Courts.CourtName,
       Convert(varchar,CaseHearings.GeneralDate, 106) AS GeneralDate,
       CaseHearings.IsHearingDate
FROM Cases
LEFT JOIN CaseHearings ON Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID= CaseHearings.fk_Cases_CaseHearings_CaseID
AND ((@DateFrom =''
      AND @DateTo ='')
     OR (Cases.CaseEntryDateTime >= @DateFrom
         AND Cases.CaseEntryDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo) ) )
LEFT JOIN ConcernedOffices ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID= Cases.fk_ConcernedOffices_Cases_ConcernedOfficeID
LEFT JOIN Courts ON Courts.pk_Courts_CourtID= CaseHearings.fk_Courts_CaseHearings_CourtID
INNER JOIN Web_Users ON Web_Users.UserID= Cases.fk_WebUsers_Cases_UserID
WHERE (@CaseNo =''
       OR (@CaseNo!=''
           AND Cases.CaseNo LIKE '%'+ @CaseNo +'%'))
  AND Cases.CaseTitle LIKE '%'+@CaseTitle+'%' END
```

Comment: `@DateFrom ='' AND @DateTo =''`- should likely be using NULL checks

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen My mind has kinda stopped working and can't figure out the problem, could you please correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You have used @DateFrom and @DateTo in the join which means this condition is checked while joining data between tables. You should use this condition in where clause in order to filter records based on your condition.

Comment: Nahi bhai, meine woh bhi check ki, kaam nahi krti

Comment: Try to remove other conditions in where clause and just add this one to check if other conditions in where clause does not have any problem.